# Clone image inside a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In the code I am writing I am attempting to clone a picture from inside a list and insert it inside a div. The image is also draggable to the div.

For reference this is how I have my image in my HTML code

```
  <img id="drag1" src="https://pixabay.com/get/19b738fe047c3bf9d39b/1440605897/smiley-163510_1280.jpg?direct" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width=200px length=200px>
```

Here is part of my test.js code:

```
$("#buttona").click(function () {

  $('#drag1').clone().insertAfter("#maindiv");

});
```

I have two issues.

1. How to I get it to copy inside my div. I only am aware of .insertAfter or .insertBefore
2. Currently I can get it to insert the clone image after the div I want but the cloned image is behind another image. How can I get it to show up in front. I tried changing the z-index of the 2 images but it didnt change anything for the clone image, it was still behind the other image.

Comment: Answer to your 1st question. Update `$('#drag1').clone().insertAfter("#maindiv");` to `$('#drag1').clone().appendTo("#maindiv");`

Answer (score 0):

The commenter is correct, use `.appendTo()` instead of `.insertAfter()`.  For an image to respect `z-index`, it must be either relatively or absolutely positioned, so in your CSS:

```
<some-image-selector-rule> {
   position: absolute; --or--
   position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're question is two fold. The first being how to insert the image. For this jQuery has several helpful methods including [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/), [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/), [`.appendTo`](http://api.jquery.com/appendto/), etc. For a full list of jQuery DOM manipulation functions see this [list](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/).

On to your questions. A simple solution would be to use:

```
$("#buttona").click(function () {
    $('#drag1')
        .clone()
        .attr('id', 'drag2')   // <-- Note this line
        .appendTo("#maindiv");
});
```

Note the added **`.attr('id', 'drag2')`**. It is invalid to have two elements within the DOM with the same ID. Once you clone the element, you'll need to change the ID.

As for your second question, `z-index` only applies to elements that contain a `position` attribute. See [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) MDN article for reference. To get this image to show above the other, you'll need to modify your CSS:

```
#drag2 {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

or inline the CSS as part of your previous operation:

```
$("#buttona").click(function () {
    $('#drag1')
        .clone()
        .attr('id', 'drag2')
        .css({ 'position': 'relative', 'z-index': 1 })
        .appendTo("#maindiv");
});
```

You're `z-index` problem may be solved for you however, by placing the image in the correct location (i.e. inside the `<div>` instead of after it). Try that fix first to see if the `z-index` is really needed.

Comment: Thank sorry for getting back so late but this solution worked for me.